# Spoilers should allow advanced formatting

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-deferred, spoilers

With standard quotes, you can use advanced formatting, such as paragraphs.

> ```
> > Sentence 1.
> >
> > Sentence 2.
> ```
>
> > Sentence 1.
> >
> > Sentence 2.

However, this is impossible with spoiler blockquotes.

> ```
> >! Sentence 1.
> >!
> >! Sentence 2.
> ```
>
> > Sentence 1.
> >
> >  Sentence 2.

I think the spoilers should behave the save way as standard block quotes. Sometimes, it's nice to put a big explanation of the code in a spoiler, and currently I'm forced to use ugly `<br>`.

The issue is most likely caused by that spoiler block quotes are a hack, involving checking if the block quote begins with `!` after rendering Markdown. This should be a part of Stack Exchange Markdown implementation in my opinion, not something implemented over actual Markdown.

Comment: @AdamLear Any update on the corresponding [MSE feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116613/355458)?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Nothing new. I added a link to it to our internal tracker for this issue, though.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, definitely a bug, but for now instead of `<br>` you could end each line with two spaces.

> Foo
>
>  Bar

Comment: Isn't... that what you do with normal markdown?

Comment: @TheDoctor With "normal" markdown, two newlines is a paragraph break. Adding two spaces after every line is a workaround for this.

Answer (score 4):

It would be worth posting a bug report at [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) if it hasn't already been done.

In the meantime:

```
>! <p>You can still use HTML markup to format spoiler text.</p>
>! <ul>
>! <li>`Like this,`</li>
>! <li>for example</li>
>! </ul>
>! <h2>Or this, even.</h2>
```

> You can still use HTML markup to format spoiler text.
>
> - `Like this,`
> - for example
>
> ### Or this, even.

Comment: It could be [moved if neccessary](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/). I'm just not sure how relevant this is to the entire network - I doubt that other sites need spoilers with paragraphs.

Comment: @xfix There was [another bug with spoiler formatting](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/809/11006) that was recently fixed after a bug report was posted at [meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136589/242137). (It took a while for the admins to get round to it, mind you.) I think all the beta sites use identical themes, so the bug is almost certainly replicated in other places besides codegolf.

Comment: Please no. HTML is so annoying to edit and view. -_-